# Multiplying values within two lists and printing them out python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, function

I am trying to make it so that I can multiply each cost with the corresponding number of products sold. For example, 1.99 * 10, 1.49 * 5 and so on. Also, I can't seem to figure out how I can print out the product name for the most expensive or the least expensive product according to the costs in the list. I tried multiplying i in product_cost with the corresponding i of product_sold, but the answer seems to be way off. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Thanks

However, with the code below,

```
# product lists
product_names = ["prime numbers", "multiplication tables", "mortgage calculator"]
product_costs = [1.99, 1.49, 2.49]
product_sold = [10, 5, 15]

def report_product():
    total = 0
    print("Most expensive product:", max(product_costs))
    print("Least expensive product:", min(product_costs))
    for i in range(len(product_costs)):
        total += i * product_sold[i]
    print("Total value of all products:", total)

selection = ""

while selection != "q":
    selection = input("(s)earch, (l)ist, (a)dd, (r)emove, (u)pdate, r(e)port or (q)uit: ")

    if selection == 'q':
        break
    elif selection == 's':
        search_product()
    elif selection == "l":
        list_products()
    elif selection == "a":
        add_products()
    elif selection == "r":
        remove_products()
    elif selection == "u":
        update_products()
    elif selection == "e":
        report_product()
    else:
        print("Invalid option, try again")

print("Thanks for looking at my programs!")
```

Comment: Off topic: `if selection == 'q':         break` is redundant since the while loop's condition is `while selection != 'q'` making the loop break anyways

Comment: can u show code for search_product,list_products,remove_products,update_products,report_product functions..??

Answer (score 1):

Although not necessarily optimal, you can get an answer with minimal code using `zip()`:

```
def report_product():

    print('Most expensive product:', max(zip(product_costs, product_names))[1])

    print('Least expensive product:', min(zip(product_costs, product_names))[1])

    total_earned = sum(cost * sold for cost, sold in zip(product_costs, product_sold))

    print('Total earned from all products sold: ${:.2f}'.format(total_earned))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Most expensive product: mortgage calculator
Least expensive product: multiplication tables
Total earned from all products sold: $64.70
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a new array of the corresponding indices multiplied,

```
product_costs = [1.99, 1.49, 2.49]
product_sold = [10, 5, 15]
product_mult = list(map(lambda x,y: x*y, product_costs,product_sold))
```

To find the name of which product was most expensive,

```
index = product_costs.index(max(product_costs))
most_expensive = product_names[index]
```

Comment: The code `[x*y for x in product_costs for y in product_sold]` produces all nine possible products: `[19.9, 9.95, 29.85, 14.9, 7.45, 22.35, 24.900000000000002, 12.450000000000001, 37.35]` not the three the OP is looking for.

Comment: The code `index = product_mult.index(max(product_mult))` finds the product that *earned* the most, not necessarily the most *expensive* product.

Comment: Oh oops, misread the question! Thanks once again for the catch, will have to be sharper when answering stuff :/

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> prod_m = [a*b for a,b in zip(product_costs, product_sold)]
>>> prod_m
[19.9, 7.45, 37.35]
>>> product_names[product_costs.index(max(product_costs))]
'mortgage calculator'
>>> product_names[product_costs.index(min(product_costs))]
'multiplication tables'
```

You can also use numpy for multiplying two lists.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> list(numpy.array(product_costs)*numpy.array(product_sold))
[19.899999999999999, 7.4500000000000002, 37.350000000000001]
```